# (Ruby,Rails) Context of SELF in modules and libraries...?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope, self

Quick question regarding the use of "SELF" inside a module or library.  Basically what is the scope/context of "SELF" as it pertains to a module or library and how is it to be properly used?  For an example of what I'm talking about, check out the "AuthenticatedSystem" module installed with "restful_authentication".

NOTE:  I'm aware that 'self' equates to 'this' in other languages and how 'self' operates on a class/object, however in the context of a module/library there is nothing to 'self'.  So then what is the context of self inside something like a module where there is no class?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

In a module:

When you see `self` in an instance method, it refers to the instance of the class in which the module is included.

When you see `self` outside of an instance method, it refers to the module.

```
module Foo
  def a
    puts "a: I am a #{self.class.name}"
  end

  def Foo.b
    puts "b: I am a #{self.class.name}"
  end

  def self.c
    puts "c: I am a #{self.class.name}"
  end
end

class Bar
  include Foo

  def try_it
    a
    Foo.b # Bar.b undefined
    Foo.c # Bar.c undefined
  end
end

Bar.new.try_it
#>> a: I am a Bar
#>> b: I am a Module
#>> c: I am a Module
```

Comment: Precisely. Everything is an object in Ruby. There is no place code can be executed where there isn't a self.

Comment: Understood, so then what is the scope/purpose of calling self in a module?

Comment: Hi All,

Still looking for an explicit answer.  I realize what SELF *can* do.  What I need to know is exactly what it *does* do in a function of a module?  I would guess that some type of variable is set globally, but I'm not sure if this is the case.  Can anyone confirm/enlighten?

Comment: I guess I don't really understand your question. What does it do? It serves as a reference to the enclosing object. In a module, outside of an instance method, it serves as a reference to the module itself. In a module but inside an instance method, it serves as a reference to the instance of the enclosing class.

Answer (score 0):

For a short summary...
http://paulbarry.com/articles/2008/04/17/the-rules-of-ruby-self

self is also used to add class methods (or static methods for C#/Java people). The following snippet is adding a method called do_something to the current class object (static)...

```
class MyClass
    def self.do_something   # class method
       # something
    end
    def do_something_else   # instance method
    end
end
```