# Ruby - Using Mixins to get a Parent Variable calculated in a Module

Tags: ruby, variables, module, parent-child, mixins

Thanks a lot for your help.
I have a Parent, a Child and a Module in two separate files. `player_fabrizio` is the Instance of the `Player` class, which is child of `Settings`. The instance `player_fabrizio` needs to use the `@totalmoney` variable of the instance `new_settings`.

```
require_relative "modules_test"

class Settings
    include Variables
    attr_reader :totalmoney
end

class Player < Settings
    def initialize(kingdom, king)
        @playerData = [kingdom, king]
    end
    def calculate
        print @totalmoney
    end
end

new_settings = Settings.new
new_settings.globalSettings(100, 2)

player_fabrizio = Player.new("MyDinasty", "Fabrizio")
player_fabrizio.calculate                # no output
```

This is the file modules_test.rb. `new_setting` uses the method `globalSettings` of the `module Variables` to set the `@totalmoney` variable.

```
module Variables
    def globalSettings(totalmoney, nplayer)
        @totalmoney = totalmoney
        return @totalmoney
    end
end
```

The result of the method `player_fabrizio.calculate` should be 100, but instead no output is give.
I searched the forum, but I was not able to find a question. I read a question that had a similar issue, but I was not able to find an answer.

Thanks a lot for you help
Fabrizio

([Ruby, mixin instance variables and methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16869832/ruby-mixin-instance-variables-and-methods))

Comment: you are not trying to fetch a variable from parent class here. Instead you are trying to fetch it from some other object of the parent class

Comment: `@total_money` will be stored in the instantiated object and not in the class itself. `new_settings` is a instance of `Settings` class while `player_fabrizio`is an instance of the `Player` class that is not aware of the `new_settings` object.

Comment: @lcguida yes, the concept of `instance` and `class` variable was not clear to me at that time, but it was even less clear to me how to easily retrieve the object instances and pass it to another object. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rename `Settings` to `Game` and do it as follows (though you are free to use whatever name suits you):

```
class Game
  include Variables
  attr_reader :totalmoney
end

class Player
  attr_reader :game

  def initialize(game, kingdom, king)
    @game = game
    @playerData = [kingdom, king]
  end

  def calculate
    print game.totalmoney
    # rest of the logic here
  end
end

game = Game.new
game.globalSettings(100, 2)

player_fabrizio = Player.new(game, "MyDinasty", "Fabrizio")
player_fabrizio.calculate
```

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: @Chowlett's solution looks good too. It will work (and is better solution) if you have global settings for all the players you will be creating. Instead if you can create multiple games with different settings, then you could use this one.

Comment: Thank to everyone for the amazing help. I could not understand this alone.
Regards 
Fabrizio

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation to my first question on StackOverflow, it helped me better understand the concepts of Object Oriented Programming. It was hard for me to understand abstract concepts, but these comments and answers made it very clear!

I learn from this question to avoid too much abstraction in programming.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - you're setting `@totalmoney`, which is an *instance* member variable of `new_settings`, so `player_fabrizio` has no access to it. You probably want to set a *class* member variable of `Settings`.

In more detail - the module is a bit of a side issue here. By including `Variables` into `Settings`, you are effectively pasting the code of `Variables` into `Settings`. So what you have is equivalent to this:

```
class Settings        
    attr_reader :totalmoney

    def globalSettings(totalmoney, nplayer)
        @totalmoney = totalmoney
        return @totalmoney
    end
end

class Player < Settings
    def initialize(kingdom, king)
        @playerData = [kingdom, king]
    end
    def calculate
        print @totalmoney
    end
end

new_settings = Settings.new
new_settings.globalSettings(100, 2)

player_fabrizio = Player.new("MyDinasty", "Fabrizio")
player_fabrizio.calculate                # no output
```

By the end of this, you have a `Settings` object called `new_settings`, with `@totalmoney` set to 100; and you have a `Player` object (which is also a `Settings`) named `player_fabrizio`, which doesn't have `@totalmoney` set at all.

What you may want is the following:

```
class Settings        
    def self.globalSettings(totalmoney, nplayer)
        @@totalmoney = totalmoney
    end
end

class Player < Settings
    def initialize(kingdom, king)
        @playerData = [kingdom, king]
    end
    def calculate
        print @@totalmoney
    end
end

Settings.globalSettings(100, 2)

player_fabrizio = Player.new("MyDinasty", "Fabrizio")
player_fabrizio.calculate
```

Note the `@@` in front of `@@totalmoney`, denoting it as a *class* member. I've also made `globalsettings` a class method, so you don't need a `Settings` object in hand to change the global settings.

To be honest, though, I'm a bit dubious about inheriting `Player` from `Settings` - a player is not a special type of settings! Personally, I'd probably do something more like:

```
class Settings
    def self.globalSettings(totalmoney, nplayer)
        @@totalmoney = totalmoney
    end

    def self.totalmoney
      @@totalmoney
    end
end

class Player
    def initialize(kingdom, king)
        @playerData = [kingdom, king]
    end
    def calculate
        print Settings.totalmoney
    end
end

Settings.globalSettings(100, 2)

player_fabrizio = Player.new("MyDinasty", "Fabrizio")
player_fabrizio.calculate
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer to my first StackOverflow question, in December 2016 I just started learning Ruby and It was very hard to understand the concepts of Object Oriented Programming. Thanks!