# Confusion about SessionsHelper, specifically the current_user method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

I am learning Rails from Michael Hartl's tutorial, but I am really confused about the SessionsHelper module. Not enough information is provided about the duplication of the `current_user` method. Could someone explain why there are two and what are their individual purposes?

```
module SessionsHelper

  def sign_in(user)
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
    self.current_user = user
  end

  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
  end

end
```

I understand the `sign_in` method would trigger the call to `current_user=(user)` but why the `current_user` method again? I understand the second method gets the user based on `remember_token` from the database, but I can't connect the dots regarding these.

Answer (score 2):

`current_user` is the `reader` method and `current_user=` is the `writer` method for your attribute `current_user`. These two are separate methods, one would be used to read the value and other to write value of current_user.

**EDIT**

In your case, `current_user=` method means that set the value of instance variable `@current_user` equal to the passed value(user).

```
def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
end
```

`current_user` method means,

```
def current_user
    ## if @current_user = nil then   
    ## set @current_user = User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
    ## else return @current_user

    @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
end
```

`sign_in` method,

```
def sign_in(user)
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
    self.current_user = user
end
```

`sign_in` method would be called as `sign_in user` from a controller.

Like Aaron mentioned in the comment, without `self`, Ruby would simply create a local variable called `current_user` which would be lost once `sign_in` method finishes execution.

But by saying, `self.current_user = user` the value of current_user would be preserved in the current instance(instance of controller in which you have included the module) of class.

For a better understanding of `self` refer to this [Stackoverflow question on self](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/963378/ruby-rails-context-of-self-in-modules-and-libraries)

Comment: So current_user method just returns the @current_user variable thats pulled from the DB? Also could you explain what is the self method doing there in the sign_in method? I thought self was only used in models to refer to that record being pulled from the database.

Comment: The `self.` is telling ruby to use the `current_user=` method on the instance of the class rather than making a new local variable called `current_user` and assigning the `user` to it only to have it go out of scope.

Comment: @TazMan Check my updated answer. See if it clears your doubts.