# params is not visible in some sinatra helper functions

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have a problem with params visibility the function `find_agency`:

Code:

require 'sinatra/base'

```
module Sinatra
  module AgencyRightsHelper
    def self.find_agency
      @agency = nil
      if !params[:agency_id].nil? then
        @agency = Agency.find(params[:agency_id]) and return
      end
    end

def before_get_agency rights_params
  AgencyRightsHelper::find_agency
end
  end
  helpers AgencyRightsHelper
end
```

Error:

```
2017-05-10 00:01:26 - NoMethodError - undefined method `params' for Sinatra::AgencyRightsHelper:Module:
    /Users/dali/perso/spacieux-be/app/helpers/agency_rights_helper.rb:18:in `before_get_agency'
    /Users/dali/perso/spacieux-be/app/helpers/rights_helper.rb:61:in `before_action'
```

params is visible in other helpers function where no self is used but I feel obliged to use it the re-use a function in the helper itself.

Answer (score 0):

`find_agency` is a class method meaning it doesn't have access to attributes and methods of a specific instance, so you won't be able to access `params` of a given instance of a Sinatra Application class (see [(Ruby,Rails) Context of SELF in modules and libraries...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/963378/ruby-rails-context-of-self-in-modules-and-libraries)). Instead you could create a module like this:

```
module AgencyRightsHelper
  def find_agency
    @agency = Agency.find(params[:agency_id]) if params[:agency_id].present?
  end
end
```

You can then use this method e.g. in a `before` block in your Sinatra Application class.

Comment: That was my original code but I cannot use the helper function in the same helper itself. It cannot find the function.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood correctly, but you can easily add another function to `AgencyRightsHelper` and call it from `find_agency`. Can you show me your full Sinatra App class code?